# a discontinuous function the square of which is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

give an example of a discontinuous function the square of which is continuous. The domain is $[0,1]$.

I tried to use the indicator function of rationals, but its square is not continuous.

EDIT:I am sorry that I did not express the question clearly, but the function should be nowhere continuous on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ and define $f$ by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x\in A \\ -1 & x\notin A \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Try the function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ where

$$
f(x) \;\; =\;\; \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if} \; x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
-1, & \text{if} \; x \not\in\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}.
$$